# Replace instead update

Tags: mongodb, indexing, collections

I have parent document with references. The question is, it is OK to delete all referenced documents and insert new ones, instead updating old, inserting new and deleting removed documents? In SQL it's not very good practice, be cause index becomes fragmented.

Comment: do u want to update the whole document or just some attributes?

Comment: Well, imagine, I have invoice with referenced products. When someone editing invoice and saves it, i dont want to check, which products are removed, witch of them updated/inserted. I just want to remove all old products and put new ones there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you start inserting documents into MongoDB, it puts each
>   document right next to the previous one on disk. Thus, if a document
>   gets bigger, it will no longer fit in the space it was originally
>   written to and will be moved to another part of the collection

i believe its better to remove and insert incase we are not sure of the size, else if the size of update is bigger we can face performance concerns in case of relocating.

If i am not wrong, what you are trying to achieve is the behavior of **Document replacement**, i believe you can use `db.collection.findAndModify()` , it has **update** and **remove** field, which can help you achieve your desired behavior.